# ExactTarget Mobile Push contacts are unsubscribed before they even exist

Tags: exacttarget

Currently testing an iPhone app using ExactTargets Mobile Push SDK. Everything seems to be set up properly, but when a device is opted-in and a Contact is automatically created it will have an opt-out date time around 10-15 min before the opt-in occurred. Also, the opt-out source is serviceFeedback, but I have been unable to find any documentation on what that means.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGvpW.png

Comment: Did you find any solution reason or anything? I've just faced the same problem